# Data Explorer generates malformed links for user websites

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

This is a tiny bug on the Data Explorer site. In the user details page, the link href to the user's website is missing the colon in the protocol specifier (e.g. `http//example.org` instead of `http://example.org`). The link text is displayed correctly.

Example: https://data.stackexchange.com/users/7784/jli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually producing a link element like the following:

```
<a href="http://http://example.org">http://example.org</a>
```

...which your browser interpreted as a link to `http://http//example.org`. Either way, not what you wanted.

I'm not entirely sure that the way those attributes are handled at the moment makes the most sense, but for the time being I've [gone ahead and made sure](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=53f5b7f9aa5527abbe415c33a9c32beb3b3246e7) that the `http://` is only added when the provided URL doesn't already start with it or `https://`.

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't realize that I wasn't supposed to include the protocol in the url.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure why the code originally had that restriction.

Comment: Seems like this is still occurring.

Comment: The code hasn't been deployed yet, because there's a backlog of changes that need to be reviewed. I'll see if I can get that process sped up a bit...sorry about the delay!